# ¿Cómo enviar datos de una vista PHP a un formulario editar PHP a través de un botón editar usando Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Sucede que tengo un archivo PHP llamado vistaArea donde listo todos los registros de mi BD y al momento de pulsar en el `btn-editar` este debe re-dirigirme a un PHP editaArea donde se debe cargar los datos que se muestra en la tabla para su posterior modificación, si la modificación es exitosa mostrar un mensaje de éxito en vistaArea caso contrario mostrar mensaje de error en editaArea.

El otro problema que tengo es que estoy usando un `button` para realizar la acción de editar, pero este no me redirige a editaArea, probé con el evento click pero solo funciona para el primer registro y en los demás no hace nada.

Para mostrar los mensajes estoy usando alertifyjs, mi código es el siguiente:

**PHP vistaArea donde listo los registros**

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-responsive-md table-sm text-center" id="tb-area">
  <thead>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Acciones</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php          
    require_once '../controlador/controladorArea.php';
    $registros=1;
    foreach ((array) $objArea as $campos): 
      $datos=$campos->id_area."-".$campos->nom_area;
      ?>
      <tr>                
        <td><?php echo $registros++?></td>
        <td><?php echo $campos->nom_area?></td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" name="btn-editar" id="btn-editar" onclick="obtenerArea(<?php echo $datos?>)"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" onclick="confirmaEliminacion(<?php echo $campos->id_area?>)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
        </td>                
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Archivo JS donde tengo las funciones para obtener y actualizar datos**

```
function obtenerArea(datos){
    var d=datos.split('-');
    /*Estos son los campos de mi PHP editaArea donde deberían asignarse los valores
    que trae "datos" desde vistaArea para después puedan actualizarse*/
    $('#id-up').val(d[0]);
    $('#area-up').val(d[1]);
    /* Un intento fallido de redireccionar a editaArea con los datos obtenidos
    document.location.href='editaArea.php';*/
}

function actualizaArea(){
    var cadena=$('#frmAreaEdit').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../controlador/controladorArea.php',
        data: cadena,
        success:function(response){
            if(response){                
                /*En estas líneas refresco vistaArea y supuestamente 
                mostrar el mensaje de éxito pero no hace nada
                $('#container-add').load('vistaArea.php #frmArea');
                $('#container-area').load('vistaArea.php #tb-area');
                alertify.success("Actualizado exitosamente!");*/
            }else{
                /*Este mensaje debería mostrarse en el editaArea si falló la modificación*/
                alertify.error("Falló la solicitud!");
            }
        }        
    });
}
```

**PHP editaArea donde deben cargar los datos de vistaArea al pulsar el btn-editar**

```
<form action="" method="post" id="frmAreaEdit">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id-up" name="id-up" hidden>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="area-up" name="area-up">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btn-actualizar" id="btn-actualizar" onclick="actualizaArea();return false;">Actualizar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Podrias usar un modal de `Bootstrap` en lugar de un formulario.  Luego mandas la informacion por Ajax

Comment: Si es con un modal debería ir dentro de mi archivo vistaArea y luego realizar el editar verdad. Ahora si no usara el modal es posible realizarlo de la forma en que lo estoy trabajando o me veo obligado a usar el modal?

Comment: Si es posible realizaro con dos archivos diferentes, pero tendrias que redirigir a la otra pagina y pasar los datos por el URL.

Comment: Si contemple esa alternativa, pero no me parece muy viable ya que el usuario tiene la posibilidad de modificar los `id` en la `URL` y si digitara uno que no existe el sistema daría error. Por ello intente usar Ajax para pasar los datos por `POST` y no por `GET`.

Comment: En ese caso, tu mejor opcion es un modal y Ajax.

Comment: Solo para tener algo en claro, si uso el modal en que parte del HTML se ubican. En el `body` o al final de las etiquetas `HTML` ya que probé en ambas ubicaciones y funciona sin problemas pero quisiera saber como se ubican correctamente.

Comment: Cualquiera de las dos esta bien.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes una brecha de lógica muy grande. Corrijamos el primer issue.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" 
   name="btn-editar" id="btn-editar" 
   onclick="obtenerArea(<?php echo $datos?>)">
     <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
</button>
```

Ahora, considero que no es necesario enviar todo el set de datos, visualmente en la URL no es muy amigable. Con el ID es más que suficiente aunque tendrá que cambiar un poco la lógica de `editaArea.php`

Tu botón puede quedar perfecto así

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" 
   onclick="location.href='path/editaArea.php?id=".$campos->id_area."'">
     <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
</button>
```

Lo puedes hacer también por Javascript y no pasa nada, hay muchas formas de solucionar esto.
Cuando des click, te enviará a la otra URL algo así por ejemplo

```
localhost/path/editaArea.php?id=1
```

¿Qué tienes que hacer en editaArea?

```
$id  = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT id, area FROM areas where id = " . $id;
```

Es decir, haces una consulta y recuperas el área que le dieron click mediante un ID.
Ahora si, ya tienes el primer issue resuelto, vamos por el siguiente.

```
<form action="" method="post" id="frmAreaEdit">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id-up" name="id-up" hidden>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="area-up" name="area-up">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btn-actualizar" id="btn-actualizar" onclick="actualizaArea();return false;">Actualizar</button>
</form>
```

Tienes este formulario, debes poner los values con el retorno de la consulta anterior, la que hiciste para traer desde la otra vista el ID. Hay un error conceptual para usar el form y el AJAX. La naturaleza del formulario con el botón de tipo submit hará que la información se envíe antes que tu AJAX entre en acción. Como no estás cortando las acciones naturales del formulario este se enviará y fallará por que su propiedad `action` no sabe a donde ir, esto independientemente de que haya un AJAX escrito, lo resolvemos

```
<form id="frmAreaEdit">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id-up" name="id-up" value="<?php echo $datos_query['id']; ?>" hidden>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="area-up" name="area-up" value="<?php echo $datos_query['area']; ?>">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btn-actualizar" id="btn-actualizar">Actualizar</button>
</form>

<script>
  //Cuando el dom este listo
  $( () => {

   //Listener para cuando se envie el formulario
   $(document).on('submit', '#frmAreaEdit', function (e) {
     //Cortamos las acciones naturales del form
     e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();

    //Esto hará que ahora si entre el AJAX
    var cadena=$(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../controlador/controladorArea.php',
        data: cadena,
        success:function(response){
            if(response){                
                /*En estas líneas refresco vistaArea y supuestamente 
                mostrar el mensaje de éxito pero no hace nada
                $('#container-add').load('vistaArea.php #frmArea');
                $('#container-area').load('vistaArea.php #tb-area');
                alertify.success("Actualizado exitosamente!");*/
            }else{
                /*Este mensaje debería mostrarse en el editaArea si falló la modificación*/
                alertify.error("Falló la solicitud!");
            }
        }        
    });
   });

  });
</script>
```

Recuerda agregar las librerías correspondientes como Jquery y Bootstrap. Este modelo es una corrección a lo que intentas hacer, sin embargo hay soluciones más específicas como lo que  comentó @alancfm, con un modal, así no sales de la ventana principal y estarías haciendo una SPA muy elegante.

Te lo dejo a tu consideración.

Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu explicación detallada, pero justamente lo que quería evitar era enviar el `id` por la `URL` ya que un usuario malintencionado puede modificar el `id`. Por ello intenté guardar los datos en una variable la cual intentaba pasar por `POST`. La mejor solución será crear un modal como indicó @alancfm.